# Use Applescript as timer

Tags: timer, applescript

I have an AppleScript application that connects to a Numbers spreadsheet.

Within a repeat loop, it records the current date every 10 seconds and updates a spreadsheet cell.

I need a way of stopping the timer, recording the final 'current date' in a different table/cell and quitting the AppleScript application (not Numbers).

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the condition to exit the repeat loop.

You can leave an indeterminate repeat loop with

- `repeat until` / `repeat while` if the following boolean expression is evaluated to `true`.
- `exit repeat` at any time.

Comment: Thanks vadian but I was hoping to be able to use something like a dialog that displayed at "stop" button which would enable the repeat loop to be exited but without bringing itself (the dialog) or Numbers to the front or making it the active app.  Perhaps I should have included that info in the original question!?

Comment: The information in the question is too broad to give a concrete answer.

Comment: OK. Is there a way of having a repeat loop AND have a display dialog with icon stop where the repeat loops until I click the stop/ok dialog?

Comment: Yes, but not simultaneously, `display dialog` works modally which means it stops until a button will be pressed.

Comment: That was the brickwall I was bumping into. Is it possible to "spawn" a display dialog that allows the repeat loop to continue but exits when the display dialog "stop" has been clicked?

Comment: Not with pure AppleScript. You could do it with an AppleScriptObjC application.

Comment: You can time out a dialog now. It's still modal, but you can at least get the dialog to come up for an arbitrary number of seconds, giving the opportunity to stop the process for n seconds, then continue. Like: `display dialog "stop?" buttons {"yes"} giving up after 3`

Comment: You can also save your script as a "stay open" application and use an idle handler (and use the above "giving up after" dialog method). Using an Idle handler is arguably a little cleaner than using a repeat loop.

Comment: @CRGreen Yes you can, but waiting for *giving up* 3 seconds in each loop is pretty annoying and you have to split the repeat loop into multiple handlers otherwise the idle handler will never be reached.

Comment: all you need is one idle handler and one quit handler. it's not that complicated. but it is annoying.

Comment: @CRGreen The `idle` handler is only called if the code is **idle** that means has exited a handler. It is not called during a repeat loop in a single handler.

Comment: The point is you don't need a repeat loop if you use an idle handler (except for repeating for reasons other than repeating the whole process). You can do anything you want in before the "return" in the idle handler. I'm going to post the example code to see if @markh can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using a "stay open" application and an idle handler to do what you want without using a repeat loop.

```
on idle
    tell me to activate 
    set q to display dialog "stop?" buttons {"yes"} giving up after 10
    if button returned of q is "yes" then
        quit
    else
        beep --replace with your Numbers stuff 
    end if
    return 10

end idle

on quit
    continue quit
end quit
```

Comment: @markh, there are two other methods. You could use the "giving up after" method with a repeat loop using just a script and not a stay open app (how annoying the dialog is is up to you), or what if you could have your script wait for you to hold down the control key? You can do this using the free third party CheckModifierKeys and do shell script: `do shell script "/usr/local/bin/checkModifierKeys control"` (so at the top of your repeat loop you use this and if it detects the control key being held down, an additional if/then ends the repeat loop)

Comment: Actually there is one more option, if you want a dedicated-window-with-button option. It works like this: to start the process, you push a button. To end it, you hit the esc key or command-period. The only drawback is that ending the loop could happen when you're doing something else in another app and hit command-period or esc (for other reasons). This is possible using Smile (free script editor). I can give you a complete answer of doing this in Smile, if you're interested. I won't bother if there's no interest.